# How to make data predictions

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling

As a total beginner I am trying to apply some "predictions" on top of a bunch of csv files which contains house transactions for the last 20 years divided per area. What I would like to predict is the trend of the transactions for lets say the next year for a specific area.

What general steps would you follow, to analyse those data and then predict?

I read different articles but what I am looking for it is a sort of "best general practice" for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression will work well if your data set is large, but only for predicting current house prices (say, for example, estimating the value of your house). That's what people generally mean when they talk about predicting house prices from current house sales data.

The question of how house prices will behave in the next year is much, but much more complicated, and would not depend simply on the data you currently have. You would need to involve other information and a much more complex model, which would need to involve things like current level of household debt, inflation rate, economic outlook, etc. Daunting.

Generally, speculative prices follow some stochastic process. They depend on the current value, but diverge more and more the farther you go in the future.

Comment: So what you reckon is that with that kind of data you cannot do that much unless of plain statistics that pretty much will give you just some insight of the current data?

Comment: You can use the data you have to predict the price of a house which is not on the current data set, but I would be careful with the time dimension. First of all you have seasonality (houses are more expensive during summer), and then there's the problem of price prediction that falls into the realm of economic forecasting.

Comment: You could naively assume that, if house prices have been rising for the past 2 years, that they will continue rising in the future, and a regression model with the correct number of parameters will give you that answer, but that will most certainly turn out to be incorrect, as the future price diverges from the current price in a way that cannot be predicted from your current data alone.

Comment: Thank you very much. It sounds like (of course) there is no magic formula about that. What it is required is a specific "domain knowledge" for the topic. Any good link you can suggest to go more in depth with regression-model?

Comment: There are quite a few good online resources on this now. [Andrew Ng's course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) is pretty good, and popular.